# Shell script with expect module to backup running config of router via console

Tags: shell, expect

I am a Linux enthusiast trying my hand at shell scripting lately.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect-f
cd /home/vuser/Net_backup
now=$(date +"%m_%d_%y")
touch  /home/vuser/Net_backup/ASR$now.txt
sleep 5s
set Password "prizer"
set password "banger"
set Trial   "32"
set bye   "exit"
set quitconsole "q"
set exitcons "logout"
spawn telnet xx.xx.xx.xx
expect "password:"
send "$password\n"
expect "admin>"
send "$Trial\n"
sleep 5s
expect "ASR1001>"
send "enable\n"
expect "Password:"
send "$Password\n"
expect "ASR1001#"
send "terminal length 0\n"
expect "ASR1001#"
send "show run\n" | tee /home/vuser/Net_backup/ASRnow.txt
expect "ASR1001#"
send "$bye\n"
sleep 5s
xdotool key ctrl+]
sleep 5s
send "$quitconsole\n"
expect "admin >"
send "$exitcons\n"
sleep 5s
exit
```

I intend to write a shell script which would perform the following functions .

(1) Create a file in a specific folder 
(2) Append the system date to the file name in the format ""%m_%d_%y""
(3) Login to a console server 
(4) access a specific port on a console server to login to the router
(5) go to the super user prompt on the router 
(6) set terminal length to 0 to negate the need for  carriage return input
(7) run the command "show run" on the router and capture this output to the file created in 
    step (2)
(8) Exit from the router command prompt
(9)Exit from the console server (this needs three steps first send keystrokes (ctrl+]) then
   the command q or quit and finally logout to comeback to the linux prompt)
(10) Exit the script .

I have written the script which is given above ..

My script however gets stuck on the console server and does not move forward, the script proceeds after I manually logout from the console server however the intended output is not achieved

Appreciate your help on this .

Thank you 
Avinash

Answer (score 1):

While developing expect scripts, you want to enable debugging output. Always add this near the top: `exp_internal 1`

This is wrong: `#!/usr/bin/expect-f` -- you need a space before the option.

Expect is not shell. These lines need to be changed:

```
now=$(date +"%m_%d_%y")
touch  /home/vuser/Net_backup/ASR$now.txt
sleep 5s
send "show run\n" | tee /home/vuser/Net_backup/ASRnow.txt
```

Use `\r` instead of `\n` to "hit enter" for your send commands.

If your expect patterns are correct, there's no need to sleep.

Here's a quick untested rewrite

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
cd /home/vuser/Net_backup
set now [clock format [clock seconds] "%m_%d_%y"]
exec touch ASR$now.txt

set Password "prizer"
set password "banger"
set Trial   "32"
set bye   "exit"
set quitconsole "q"
set exitcons "logout"

spawn telnet 192.168.95.96
expect "password:"
send "$password\r"
expect "admin>"
send "$Trial\r"
expect "ASR1001>"
send "enable\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$Password\r"
expect "ASR1001#"
send "terminal length 0\r"
expect "ASR1001#"
send "show run\r"
expect -re "(.*)ASR1001#"
set fh [open ASR$now.txt w]
puts $fh $expect_out(1,string)
close $fh

send "$bye\r"
sleep 5
send "^]"     ;# here, in your editor, enter a literal ctrl-]
sleep 5
send "$quitconsole\r"
expect "admin >"
send "$exitcons\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: The script doesnt work , I will have to try something similar though .

Comment: Hi glenn made some modifications to the script it mostly works now ,however I am not able to capture the output of the file . Please see my inputs below ...

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/expect -f
set systemTime [clock seconds]
set now [clock format $systemTime -format  "%m_%d_%y"]
exec touch ASR$now.txt
set Password "prizer"
set password "banger"
set bye "exit"
set quitconsole "q"
set exitcons "logout"
spawn  ssh admin@192.168.95.96
expect "password:"
send "$password\r"
sleep 5
expect "admin>"
send "32\r"
sleep 5
send "\r"
expect "ASR1001>"
send "enable\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$Password\r"
expect "ASR1001#"
send "terminal length 0\r"
expect "ASR1001#"
send "show run \r"
set output [open "ASR$now.txt" "w"] <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Fails here 
send "$bye\r"
sleep 5
send "ctrl-]"
sleep 5
send "$quitconsole\r"
expect "admin>"
send "$exitcons\r"
expect eof
```

Answer (score 0):

Expect scripting is entirely different from bash scripting. You cannot use bash command inside with expect interpreter.

ie, you cannot use basic commands like tee, cp, mv, rm in expect scripting.

But instead you can configure tftp in you local machine and use the below command in your expect script.

```
send "copy running-config tftp://$tftp/$config\n\n"
expect "$tftp"
send "\n"
```

> The script should be like,

```
#!/usr/bin/expect-f
cd /home/vuser/Net_backup
now=$(date +"%m_%d_%y")
touch  /home/vuser/Net_backup/ASR$now.txt
sleep 5s
set Password "prizer"
set password "banger"
set Trial   "32"
set bye   "exit"
set quitconsole "q"
set exitcons "logout"
spawn telnet xx.xx.xx.xx
expect "password:"
send "$password\n"
expect "admin>"
send "$Trial\n"
sleep 5s
expect "ASR1001>"
send "enable\n"
expect "Password:"
send "$Password\n"
expect "ASR1001#"
send "terminal length 0\n"
expect "ASR1001#"
send "copy running-config tftp://$tftp/$config\n\n" #edit this line wrt your local machine's configurations
expect "$tftp"
send "\n"
expect "ASR1001#"
send "$bye\n"
sleep 5s
xdotool key ctrl+]
sleep 5s
send "$quitconsole\n"
expect "admin >"
send "$exitcons\n"
sleep 5s
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an working solution.** I have tested it using one Cisco device connected to my Debian 9 Stretch VM.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
cd /var/www/html/Netbackup
set systemTime [clock seconds]
set now [clock format $systemTime -format  "%m_%d_%y"]
exec touch R1$now.txt
sleep 1
spawn telnet 192.168.10.100
sleep 1
expect "Username:"
send "cisco\n"
sleep 1
expect "Password:"
send "cisco\n"
sleep 1
expect "R1"
send "terminal length 0\n"
expect "R1#"
send "show run\n"
sleep 2
expect -re "(.*)R1#"
set fh [open /var/www/html/Netbackup/R1$now.txt w]
puts $fh $expect_out(1,string)
close $fh
sleep 1
xdotool key ctrl+]
sleep 1
send "$quitconsole\n"
sleep 1
send "$exitcons\n"
sleep 1
exit
```

Below are the outputs

```
root@lampserver:~/Desktop# ./Netbackup.sh
spawn telnet 192.168.10.100
Trying 192.168.10.100...
Connected to 192.168.10.100.
Escape character is '^]'.


User Access Verification

Username: cisco
Password:
R1#terminal length 0
R1#show run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 2325 bytes
!
............
Output Omitted
............
R1#can't read "bye": no such variable
    while executing
"send "$bye\n""
    (file "./Netbackup.sh" line 24)
root@lampserver:~/Desktop#
root@lampserver:~/Desktop# cd
root@lampserver:~# cd /var/www/html/Netbackup
root@lampserver:/var/www/html/Netbackup# ls
R102_14_19.txt
root@lampserver:/var/www/html/Netbackup#
root@lampserver:/var/www/html/Netbackup# ls -al
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     2583 Feb 14 17:49 R102_14_19.txt
root@lampserver:/var/www/html/Netbackup#
```